# Redirecting HTTPS to Sub-Domain with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect both
`https://website.me/` and `https://www.website.me/` to `https://es.website.me/`

---

This rule doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://es.website.me/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: you just want to permanent redirect https://www.website.me/ redirect to https://es.website.me/ right ?

Comment: alone  ¨´HTTPS¨   (https://)website.me/ redirect to :>>> https://es.website.me/

Comment: ok try .htaccess #301 redirection rules given below in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use below htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://es.website.me/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for redirection in your case:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.me$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.me$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://es.website.me/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to redirect, or rewrite?

To redirect with a code 301  (permanently moved), make 2 virtual hosts; one for the real site, and one for all the URL's you want to redirect. In the redirect host, add this line:

`Redirect 301 / https://es.website.me/`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to redirect only if HTTPS is already used, you must check for it, together with the hostname of course.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://es.website.me%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. Never test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).